# How to disable edit post option after period of time?

Tags: posts

How to disable edit post option for post one day after publication?

Comment: I solved this issue. If somebody need the solution just ask me. I'll post it here.

Comment: Alexey I would like to view your solution top this.

Comment: Please do post your solution as an answer, so it could be of use to others. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok! @Kieran and @Rarst, here it is :)

```
function stoppostedition_filter( $capauser, $capask, $param){

  global $wpdb;   

  $post = get_post( $param[2] );

  if( $post->post_status == 'publish' ){

      // Disable post edit only for authore role
      if( $capauser['author'] == 1 ){

        if( ( $param[0] == "edit_post") || ( $param[0] == "delete_post" ) ) {

          // How much time have passed since post publication
          $post_time_unix = strtotime( str_replace('-', ':', $post->post_date ) );
          $current_time_unix = time();
          $diff = $current_time_unix - $post_time_unix; 
          $hours_after_publication = floor( $diff / 60 / 60 );

          // If 24 hours have passed since the publication than remove capability to edit and delete post
          if( $hours_after_publication >= 24 ){

            foreach( (array) $capask as $capasuppr) {

              if ( array_key_exists($capasuppr, $capauser) ) {

                $capauser[$capasuppr] = 0;

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
  return $capauser;
}
add_filter('user_has_cap', 'stoppostedition_filter', 100, 3 );
```

Answer (score 4):

Nice, @Alexey.  Here is a simplified version, that does not disallow Administrators from editing.  This version is more in the style of Wordpress core, as I took it from the example code on the Wordpress [user_has_cap filter codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap) and modified it.

```
function restrict_editing_published_posts( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {

    // Bail out if we're not asking to edit a post ...
    if( 'edit_post' != $args[0]
      // ... or user is admin
      || !empty( $allcaps['manage_options'] )
      // ... or user already cannot edit the post
      || empty( $allcaps['edit_posts'] ) )
        return $allcaps;

    $post = get_post( $args[2] );

    // Bail out if the post isn't published:
    if( 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $allcaps;

    // If post is older than a day ...
    if( strtotime( $post->post_date ) < strtotime( '-1 day' ) ) {
        // ... then disallow editing.
        $allcaps[$cap[0]] = false;
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'restrict_editing_published_posts', 10, 3 );
```