# How to disable edit post option 12 hours after post publication for contributors?

Tags: posts

I've tried to achieve it by using snippet from years ago, but it doesn't seem to work. I need to make it work with Gutenberg (WP 5.0).

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: What's the snippet you're trying to use?

Comment: The second one from this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26753/how-to-disable-edit-post-option-after-period-of-time - obviously I changed "author" to "contributor" and time period

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable edit post option after period of time?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26753/how-to-disable-edit-post-option-after-period-of-time)

Answer (score 2):

The other suggestions (and the accepted answer in your link) temporarily change a user's capabilities globally. That is a hack. There is hook specifically designed for conditionally adjusting capabilities for specific content: [`map_meta_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/map_meta_cap/).

When WordPress checks whether a user can edit a post, it checks if the user can `edit_post`. WordPress decides which actual capability users have that this maps to using the `map_meta_cap()` function.

For example, when checking if a user can edit a post, it checks if the post was authored by the current user. If it was, then it maps the 'meta capability' `edit_post` to the 'primitive capability' `edit_posts`. If the post was authored by someone else it maps it to `edit_others_posts`. Then it checks if the current user has the mapped capability.

So we can hook into this process so that whenever WordPress maps `edit_post` we will check if the current user is a Contributor, and if the post is older than 12 hours. If both those things are true we will map `edit_post` to `do_not_allow`, meaning that the user will not be allowed to edit it:

```
function wpse_319901_contributor_can_edit( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    // Stop if this isn't a check for edit_post or delete_post.
    if ( $cap !== 'edit_post' || $cap !== 'delete_post' ) {
        return $caps;
    }

    // Get the current user's roles.
    $user  = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $roles = $user->roles;

    // Stop if the user is not a Contributor.
    if ( ! in_array( 'contributor', $roles ) ) {
        return $caps;
    }

    // For edit_post the post ID will be the first argument in $args.
    $post = get_post( $args[0] );

    // Is the post older than 12 hours?
    if ( get_the_time( 'U', $post ) < strtotime( '-12 hours' ) ) {
        // If so, do not allow the user to edit it.
        $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    }

    return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_319901_contributor_can_edit', 10, 4 );
```

You can read more about capabilities and how meta capabilities are mapped to primitive capabilities [here](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-user-roles/).

Answer (score -1):

[How to disable edit post option after period of time?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26753/how-to-disable-edit-post-option-after-period-of-time)
Similar to this explanation you pointed out:

It's preferable to use `get_post_time()` instead accessing the global variable `$post->post_date`. This is really ugly and bad practice.By default it formats to UNIX EPOCH but to be safe pass the U argument.

PHP has a built in function `date('U')` also in UNIX EPOCH

```
<?php
function disable_editing_after_twelvehours( $post_object ) {
    $currentTime = date('U');
    $postTime = get_post_time('U',false,$post_object->ID,false);

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if($current_user->role['contributor']){
        /*Subtract current time from post time and check if it is greater 
        than 
        12hrs(43200 seconds)*/
        if(($currentTime - $postTime) > 43200 {
              $current_user->cap[0] = false;
          }
      }
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'disable_editing_after_twelvehours' );
?>
```

hooking it to the post should enable it to check all posts that load. Let me know if you have problems, as I wrote this really quick before losing my train of thought and getting busy.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, it disables editing posts after 12 hours to all users if I'm correct. I need this function to work only for contributors. Could you please modify it a bit when you will have some time?

Comment: see if that helps.

Comment: `the_post` is a very strange hook to use for this...

Comment: I suggest you actually give feedback.