# How to disable edit post option?

Tags: posts

I have a WordPress LMS site, and the Tutor Instructor role can create posts as courses and these posts are custom post types called courses, and I want to disallow the Tutor Instructor to edit their courses after they publish them.

I saw this [How to disable edit post option after period of time?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26753/how-to-disable-edit-post-option-after-period-of-time)

It doesn't work. I changed the role to Tutor Instructor and made it 1 hour but still not working, maybe because the post type is not in the code.

This is the frontend page from where the Tutor Instructor can click edit or delete, and the page will redirect him to the course builder to edit the link will be like this (https://**************.com/dashboard/create-course/?course_ID=13865).

```
<div class="mycourse-footer">
                        <div class="tutor-mycourses-stats">
                            <?php echo tutor_utils()->tutor_price( tutor_utils()->get_course_price() ); ?>
                            <div class="course-actions">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( tutor_utils()->course_edit_link( $post->ID ) ); ?>"
                                   class="tutor-mycourse-edit edit">
                                    <i class="fal fa-pencil-alt"></i><?php esc_html_e( 'Edit', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#tutor-course-delete"
                                   class="tutor-dashboard-element-delete-btn tutor-mycourse-delete"
                                   data-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>">
                                    <i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i><?php esc_html_e( 'Delete', 'edumall' ) ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php do_action( 'tutor_course_dashboard_actions_after', $post->ID ); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

The full-page code for the frontend publishing (where the Tutor Instructor can create the courses, and this is where he can edit the course).

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_tutor_header( true );
do_action( 'tutor_load_template_before', 'dashboard.create-course', null );
global $post;

$course_id          = get_the_ID();
$can_publish_course = (bool) tutor_utils()->get_option( 'instructor_can_publish_course' ) || current_user_can( 'administrator' );

if ( ! tutor_utils()->can_user_edit_course( get_current_user_id(), $course_id ) ) {
    tutor_load_template( 'permission-denied' );

    return;
}
?>

<?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_before' ); ?>
    <form action="" id="tutor-frontend-course-builder" class="tutor-frontend-course-builder" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php wp_nonce_field( tutor()->nonce_action, tutor()->nonce ); ?>

        <header id="page-header" class="page-header header-dark header-sticky-dark-logo">
            <div class="page-header-place-holder"></div>
            <div id="page-header-inner" class="page-header-inner" data-sticky="1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header-wrap">
                        <div class="header-left">
                            <?php
                            $branding_args = [
                                'reverse_scheme' => true,
                            ];
                            ?>
                            <?php edumall_load_template( 'branding', null, $branding_args ); ?>

                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="tutor-dashboard-builder-draft-btn tutor-btn bordered-btn"
                                    name="course_submit_btn"
                                    value="save_course_as_draft">
                                <i class="fal fa-save"></i>
                                <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Save', 'edumall' ); ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="header-right">
                            <div class="header-content-inner">
                                <div id="header-right-inner" class="header-right-inner">
                                    <div class="header-right-inner-content">
                                        <?php Edumall_Templates::render_button( [
                                            'link'        => [
                                                'url'         => get_the_permalink( $course_id ),
                                                'is_external' => true,
                                            ],
                                            'text'        => esc_html__( 'Preview', 'edumall' ),
                                            'icon'        => 'fal fa-glasses',
                                            'extra_class' => 'button-grey',
                                        ] ); ?>

                                        <div class="form-submit">
                                            <?php if ( $can_publish_course ) : ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="publish_course"><?php esc_html_e( 'Publish Course', 'edumall' ); ?></button>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="submit_for_review"><?php esc_html_e( 'Submit for Review', 'edumall' ); ?></button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="return-dashboard-link">
                                            <a href="<?php echo tutor_utils()->tutor_dashboard_url(); ?>"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Exit', 'edumall' ); ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php Edumall_Header::instance()->print_more_tools_button(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="tutor-frontend-course-builder-section tm-sticky-parent">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="hidden" value="tutor_add_course_builder" name="tutor_action"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="course_ID" id="course_ID" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_ID" id="post_ID" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
                        <div class="tutor-dashboard-course-builder-wrap tm-sticky-column">

                            <!--since 1.8.0 alert message -->
                            <?php
                            $instructor_can_publish = tutils()->get_option( 'instructor_can_publish_course' );
                            ?>
                            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'tutor_instructor' ) && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : ?>
                                <?php if ( isset( $_COOKIE['course_submit_for_review'] ) && ! $instructor_can_publish ) : ?>
                                    <div class="tutor-alert tutor-alert-info">
                                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Your course has been submitted to the admin. It will be published once it has been reviewed by the admins.', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!--alert message end -->

                            <?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_form_field_before' ); ?>

                            <div class="tutor-course-builder-section tutor-course-builder-info">
                                <div class="tutor-course-builder-section-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <i class="tutor-icon-down"></i><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Info', 'edumall' ); ?></span>
                                    </h3>
                                </div> <!--.tutor-course-builder-section-title-->
                                <div class="tutor-course-builder-section-content">
                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Title', 'edumall' ); ?></label>
                                            <input type="text" name="title"
                                                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>"
                                                   placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'ex. Learn photoshop CS6 from scratch', 'edumall' ); ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!--.tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope-->

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label> <?php esc_html_e( 'Description', 'edumall' ); ?></label>
                                            <?php
                                            $editor_settings = array(
                                                'media_buttons' => false,
                                                'quicktags'     => false,
                                                'editor_height' => 150,
                                                'textarea_name' => 'content',
                                            );
                                            wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'course_description', $editor_settings );
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  <!--.tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope-->

                                    <?php do_action( 'tutor/frontend_course_edit/after/description', $post ); ?>

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a category', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="tutor-form-field-course-categories">
                                                <?php //echo tutor_course_categories_checkbox($course_id);
                                                echo tutor_course_categories_dropdown( $course_id, array( 'classes' => 'tutor_select2' ) );
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a tag', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="tutor-form-field-course-tags">
                                                <?php //echo tutor_course_tags_checkbox($course_id);
                                                echo tutor_course_tags_dropdown( $course_id, array( 'classes' => 'tutor_select2' ) );
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php
                                    $monetize_by = tutils()->get_option( 'monetize_by' );
                                    if ( $monetize_by === 'wc' || $monetize_by === 'edd' ) {
                                        $course_price    = tutor_utils()->get_raw_course_price( get_the_ID() );
                                        $currency_symbol = tutor_utils()->currency_symbol();

                                        $_tutor_course_price_type = tutils()->price_type();
                                        ?>
                                        <div
                                            class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope tutor-frontend-builder-course-price">
                                            <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                                <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Price', 'edumall' ); ?></label>
                                                <div class="tutor-row tutor-align-items-center">
                                                    <div class="tutor-col-auto">
                                                        <label for="tutor_course_price_type_pro"
                                                               class="tutor-styled-radio">
                                                            <input id="tutor_course_price_type_pro" type="radio"
                                                                   name="tutor_course_price_type"
                                                                   value="paid" <?php $_tutor_course_price_type ? checked( $_tutor_course_price_type, 'paid' ) : checked( 'true', 'true' ); ?> >
                                                            <span></span>
                                                            <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                                            <span
                                                                class="tutor-input-prepand"><?php echo esc_html( $currency_symbol ); ?></span>
                                                                <input type="text" name="course_price"
                                                                       value="<?php echo esc_attr( $course_price->regular_price ); ?>"
                                                                       placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Set course price', 'edumall' ); ?>">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="tutor-col-auto">
                                                        <label class="tutor-styled-radio">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="tutor_course_price_type"
                                                                   value="free" <?php checked( $_tutor_course_price_type, 'free' ); ?> >
                                                            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Free', 'edumall' ); ?></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <!--.tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope-->
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Course Thumbnail', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <div
                                                class="tutor-form-field tutor-form-field-course-thumbnail tutor-thumbnail-wrap">
                                                <div class="tutor-row tutor-align-items-center">
                                                    <div class="tutor-col-5">
                                                        <div class="builder-course-thumbnail-img-src">
                                                            <?php
                                                            $builder_course_img_src = tutor()->url . 'assets/images/placeholder-course.jpg';
                                                            $_thumbnail_url         = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $course_id );
                                                            $post_thumbnail_id      = get_post_thumbnail_id( $course_id );

                                                            if ( ! $_thumbnail_url ) {
                                                                $_thumbnail_url = $builder_course_img_src;
                                                            }
                                                            ?>
                                                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $_thumbnail_url ); ?>"
                                                                 class="thumbnail-img"
                                                                 data-placeholder-src="<?php echo esc_url( $builder_course_img_src ); ?>">
                                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                               class="tutor-course-thumbnail-delete-btn"
                                                               style="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( 'display: %s;', $post_thumbnail_id ? 'block' : 'none' ) ); ?>">
                                                                <i class="tutor-icon-line-cross"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="tutor-col-7">
                                                        <div class="builder-course-thumbnail-upload-wrap">
                                                            <p class="builder-course-thumbnail-guide-line">
                                                                <?php echo sprintf( __( "Important Guideline: %1\$s 700x430 pixels %2\$s %3\$s File Support: %1\$s .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, or .png %2\$s no text on the image.", 'edumall' ), "<strong>", "</strong>", "<br>" ); ?>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <input type="hidden" id="tutor_course_thumbnail_id"
                                                                   name="tutor_course_thumbnail_id"
                                                                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>">
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                                                               class="tutor-course-thumbnail-upload-btn tutor-button bordered-button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload Image', 'edumall' ); ?></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_form_field_after', $post ); ?>

                            <div class="tutor-form-row tutor-form-submit">
                                <div class="tutor-form-col-12">
                                    <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-field tutor-course-builder-btn-group">
                                            <button type="submit" class="tutor-button btn-save-as-draft"
                                                    name="course_submit_btn"
                                                    value="save_course_as_draft"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save course as draft', 'edumall' ); ?></button>
                                            <?php if ( $can_publish_course ) :  ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button tutor-success" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="publish_course"><?php esc_html_e( 'Publish Course', 'edumall' ) ; ?></button>
                                            <?php else : ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button tutor-success" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="submit_for_review"><?php esc_html_e( 'Submit for Review', 'edumall' );  ?></button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="tutor-course-builder-upload-tips tm-sticky-column">
                            <h3 class="tutor-course-builder-tips-title">
                                <i class="far fa-lightbulb-on"></i><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Upload Tips', 'edumall' ); ?>
                            </h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Set the Course Price option or make it free.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Standard size for course thumbnail is 700x430.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Video section controls the course overview video.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Builder is where you create & organize a course.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Add Topics in the Course Builder section to create lessons, quizzes, and assignments.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Prerequisites refers to the fundamental courses to complete before taking this particular course.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Information from the Additional Data section shows up on the course single page.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Make Announcements to notify any important notes to all enrolled students at once.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>



<?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_after' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'tutor_load_template_after', 'dashboard.create-course', null ); ?>

<?php
get_tutor_footer( true );
```

Comment: The roles and post types which you describe are not a part of WordPress core. You will need to consult the official support channels for the extension responsible for providing these features.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will restrict all users, except admins to edit a post after one day. You can, however, change the allowed user roles or time by simply tweaking the code.

```
function wpse405644_restrict_editing() {
    
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->base == 'post' && $screen->post_type == 'courses' ) {
        $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( !in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' && (strtotime( $post->post_date ) < strtotime( '-1 day' )) ) {
                wp_die( 'You are not allowed to edit this post.');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'wpse405644_restrict_editing' );
```

You may need to change the CPT with your own.

**EDIT (Frontend Restriction)**

This code goes in your theme's `functions.php`.

```
function wpse405644_is_frontend_editing_allowed () {
    
    if ( isset($_GET['course_ID']) && !empty($_GET['course_ID']) ) {
        $post = get_post($_GET['course_ID']);
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( !in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' && (strtotime( $post->post_date ) < strtotime( '-1 day' )) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Now at the create course template, wrap the whole content section with the conditional function.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_tutor_header( true );

    if ( wpse405644_is_frontend_editing_allowed() ) {
        
        // The content BETWEEN get_tutor_header and get_tutor_footer goes here.
        
        
    } else {
        echo '<h2>You are not allowed to edit this post.</h2>';
    }
<?php get_tutor_footer( true );
```

This will show a message when the user isn't allowed to edit course.

Comment: That worked fine from the backend, but the Tutor Instructor has a page in the frontend where he can click edit and edit the course. When he clicks edit there still, he can edit it. How can I do that to the front as well?

Comment: I added the code to the post.

Comment: You can still modify this code and adapt it to work in frontend. All you need to do is remove the edit button if the criteria met.

Comment: I cant remove the edit button. I want to disallow the Tutor Instructor to edit the published course only. Because they can save it as a draft and then edit it to add the videos and files and then publish it, please could you help me?

Comment: Can't do much without seeing what code you are using for frontend publishing.

Comment: The code is added. Please check it out.

Comment: @KDot is that a common page? Or every course has it's on edit page?

Comment: This is the main page where the Tutor Instructor can create or edit the course.
the creation of the course, the link will be like this ((https://**************.com/dashboard/create-course/), and when the Tutor Instructor wants to edit the link will be like this depend on the course ID (https://**************.com/dashboard/create-course/?course_ID=13865). the edit button code is on the first code section and the create/edit page the second section above.

Comment: @KDot Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, but you forgot to add <?PHP before "else " and close it with ?> 
so the code will be like this 
<?php
    } else {
        echo '<h2>You are not allowed to edit this post.</h2>';
    } ?>